# React Auto Horizontal Scroll

Tags: reactjs, scroll, tailwind-css

I'm developing a web application with React. I want the scrollbar to scroll horizontally as my categories change.

**The application currently looks as follows:**

[image]

**But I want it to come as below. I want the scrollbar to scroll automatically.**

[image]

**The codes where I listed my categories are as follows:**

```
<div className="bg-white p-2 sticky top-0 flex space-x-4 overflow-scroll border-b border-gray-300 z-10 ">
  {categories?.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <MobileCategory
        key={index}
        categoryName={item.Title}
        active={item.Id.toString() === activeCategory}
        setActiveCategory={setActiveCategory}
        id={item.Id.toString()}
      />
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the overflow-scroll with `overflow-x-scroll`.

```
<div className="bg-white p-2 sticky top-0 flex space-x-4 overflow-x-scroll border-b border-gray-300 z-10 ">
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for each MobileCategory

then usse [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) when mounting component or changing event

```
this.foodWithOliveRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})
```